# Connect Stream Analytics to Azure Postgres - Possible?

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, azure-database-postgresql

Getting error messages. Seems this is  not possible ?

message is :

```
The JSON provided in the request body is invalid. Property 'server' value 'postgres-mydatabase123.postgres.database.azure.com' is not acceptable.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-outputs) this is not possible as currently the support output sinks are

- Azure Data Lake Store
- SQL Database Blob storage
- Event Hub
- Power BI
- Table Storage
- Service Bus Queues
- Service Bus Topics
- Azure Cosmos DB
- Azure Functions (In Preview)

Out of all of these Azure Functions or Event Hub might be interesting to you as they allow custom code to process the data. In your case that would be sending it to the PostgreSQL database.

Comment: Hi Peter - Are you saying I can send data from functions or event hub to Azure postgres?  I am currently sending iot device data to the iot hub then on to stream analytics, where I want to do 2 things - store the data, after processing in the postgresdb and also send it to powerbi.  The data from the hub is actually going from device to httptrigger function then iot hub then stream analytics.

Comment: Well, you cannot send it directly as there is no supported output but by using an azure function or an event hub you can address [the SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/connect-csharp) to output the data to Azure postgres.